# Display complete array when page is reloaded and no filtering is done

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a beginner in Angular and I was making a simple app wherein there is a employee list. I have currently hardcoded the details of imaginary employees. I have used set and get methods to filter the employee array when someone searches(wants to filter).
The problem I am having with the logic I used is that when nothing is entered in the filter box(when the page reloads or when user backspaces what was written) I want to show the complete user list but that is not happening when the page reloads . If a user enters something and then clears the search box then the full list is shown but not when page is reloaded.
Here is the ts file for that component:

```
  private _eidfilter:string='';
  get eidfilter():string {
    return this._eidfilter
  }
  set eidfilter(value : string){
    this._eidfilter=value
    this.filteredemp=this.performfilter(value.toString());
  }

  filteredemp:Emp[]=[];

performfilter(filterBy:string): Emp[] {
      if(filterBy.trim.length==0){
        return this.employees;
      }
      else{
      return this.employees.filter((employee:Emp)=>employee.eid.toString()==filterBy)
      }
    }

employees:Emp[]=[
    {eid:1,name:"Vikram",age:29,department:"WebDev",skills:5},
    {eid:2,name:"Vetaal",age:30,department:"ML",skills:3.5},]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Import ChangeDetectorRef

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

2. Inject it into Constructor

```
constructor(private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }
```

3. Use it into Your `ngOninit()` method after filling employees array.

NOTE : use this Change Detection Technique after you get data into the Array You're using.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.yourMethodToFillEmployeeDetails();
    this.chRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: I believe that it could be done using some simple methods only . For instance if my datatype was string and if I had used includes method of javascript then I would have got the complete array itself when the filter box or search box was empty

Comment: I think you've to fill your `employees:Emp[]` when the page loads, that is `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1):

For now `filteredemp` is initially empty, and receives values only on `eidfilter` change.
You can fix this by setting default value for `filteredemp`, or by filling `filteredemp` on load.